# Is there an app, where I can add things to the path variable permanently?

Tags: environment-variables, path, usability

I know it's fairly easy with simple terminal commands but I still want a program where I say
e.g.,:

```
> addtopath "~/bin"
```

and it does it permanently without me having to edit some config files and remember the correct syntax.
Is there something out there? best would be installable with apt.

Answer (score 3):

That app would be

```bash
echo 'PATH=$PATH:~/bin' >> ~/.profile
```

Feel free to put that into a shell function or a script, but honestly, I don't think it's a great tradeoff to have to install a package to get that functionality wrapped into something even simpler.

Comment: Therein lies one problem. I don't have `~/.profile` on my systems - I use `~/.bash_profile`. What if the OP uses one of the `*csh` family for their interactive shell, though. You'd need a different syntax and the command added to `~/.login`. It's not as simple as a single command until you know what that command should be for the user's environment

Comment: If op uses csh I'm sure they're less fuzzy about shell specifics, because they choose to use a shell that doesn't come as default anywhere!

Comment: OK, `s/csh/zsh/g`, which is a default on Mac now

Comment: Fair point, but that's exactly why I used .profile instead of the shell-specific .bash_profile

Comment: By the way the more I talk here the more I wish sh compatibles had come with a config system that would actually solve that

Answer (score 3):

As otherwise stated, installing a package for this seems a bit heavyweight, probably better to roll your own.

Here's a shell function that can do it, with a modicum of intelligence baked in (but there's always room for improvement):

```
addtopath() {
  local path_to_add=''
  # set var if target is a directory
  [ -d "${1}" ] && path_to_add="${1}"
  # error out if $1 was empty or a bad path was given
  : "${path_to_add:?No valid path provided}"
  # exit early if path already in PATH
  grep -qE "(^|:)${path_to_add}(:|$)" <<< "${PATH}" && return
  # add to end of .profile
  printf '\nPATH=$PATH:%s' "${path_to_add}" >> "${HOME}/.profile"
}
```

Comment: Therein lies one problem. I don't have `~/.profile` on my systems - I use `~/.bash_profile`. And what if the OP uses one of the `*csh` family for their interactive shell?. You'd need a different syntax and the command added to `~/.login`. It's not as simple as a single command until you know what that command should be for the user's environment